# Segmentation Fault when accessing char array outside function but noth within

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, readfile

so basically, thats the code producing my `segmentation fault`

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define CORRUPT_KEY_FILE    "s64581-source-key-corrupt.bin" /* ContainsKey and IV */

    #define DEBUG               1

    /**
     * Reads content of a given file and writes it into a buffer
     * 
     * @param filename Path of the file to be read
     * @param buffer Pointer to the buffer to write into
     * @param length Variable to store the filelength into
     * 
     * @return EXIT_FAILURE if an error occurred opening th File, otherwise EXIT_SUCCESS
     */
    int readFiletoBuffer(const char* filename, unsigned char* buffer, int* length) {

        int i;

        if(DEBUG) printf("\n\nFunction readFileToBuffer(..) called\n");

        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
        if(!file) {
            printf("Error opening file %s", filename);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        fseek(file, 0 , SEEK_END);
        *length = ftell(file);
        rewind(file);

        if(DEBUG) printf("\tLength of File %s: %d\n",filename ,*length);

        buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(*length+1);

        fread(buffer, *length, 1, file);
        fclose(file);

        for(i=0; i<*length; i++) printf("%d:\t%X\n",14, buffer[14]);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        unsigned char *tmp_char;
        int tmp_length, i;
        tmp_char=NULL;

        readFiletoBuffer(CORRUPT_KEY_FILE, tmp_char, &tmp_length);

        for(i=0; i<tmp_length; i++) printf("%d:\t%X\n",i, tmp_char[i]);

        return 0;
    }
```

Notice the two for loops printing the content of the buffer. The one inside the function works fine, the one in the `main`-function produces a `segmentations fault`. Why is that, and how could I fix this while allocating the needed memory within the function `readFiletoBuffer` ?

Any help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the char array you want from the function you have to pass a char** array as argument.
In that way your char* pointer will be returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CORRUPT_KEY_FILE    "s64581-source-key-corrupt.bin" /* ContainsKey and IV */

#define DEBUG               1

/**
 * Reads content of a given file and writes it into a buffer
 * 
 * @param filename Path of the file to be read
 * @param buffer Pointer to the buffer to write into
 * @param length Variable to store the filelength into
 * 
 * @return EXIT_FAILURE if an error occurred opening th File, otherwise EXIT_SUCCESS
 */
int readFiletoBuffer(const char* filename, unsigned char** buffer, int* length) {

    int i;

    if(DEBUG) printf("\n\nFunction readFileToBuffer(..) called\n");

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(!file) {
        printf("Error opening file %s", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fseek(file, 0 , SEEK_END);
    *length = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    if(DEBUG) printf("\tLength of File %s: %d\n",filename ,*length);

    *buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(*length+1);

    fread(*buffer, *length, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    for(i=0; i<*length; i++) printf("%d:\t%X\n",14, buffer[14]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char *tmp_char;
    int tmp_length, i;
    tmp_char=NULL;

    readFiletoBuffer(CORRUPT_KEY_FILE, &tmp_char, &tmp_length);

    for(i=0; i<tmp_length; i++) printf("%d:\t%X\n",i, tmp_char[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my suggestion.

Comment: thanks, i have read about it, but i forgot to access the buffer within the read function with the * when trying this out. Thank you all very much!

Comment: In order to change a pointer in a function you have to pass a pointer to that pointer so you can change the inner pointer.

Comment: sounds wiered but makes sense ;)

Comment: try it by printing the pointers. Then you will realize the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you call your function `readFiletoBuffer` with parameter `tmp_char`, this parameter will be copied! Your tmp_char is NULL after call this function!

You need to work with the pointer to this parameter to change it like this:

```
tmp_char=NULL;
readFiletoBuffer(CORRUPT_KEY_FILE, &tmp_char, &tmp_length);
```

So your function will look like this:

```
int readFiletoBuffer(const char* filename, unsigned char** buffer, int* length)
```